# yii mysql using subqueries with query builder

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am builing an app with yii and I tried doing my sql calls the "pretty way" using the yii query builder the same way seen on this guide

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

And this is my built query:

```
$diseaseCountSqlQuery = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                                    ->select ('tbl_disease.ICD10, COUNT(tbl_disease.ICD10) AS disease_count')
                                    ->from ('tbl_disease')
                                    ->join ('tbl_symptom_disease', 'ICD10=diseaseCode')
                                    ->where ($symptomsOrQueryArray)
                                    ->group ('ICD10')
                                    ->queryAll();
            //placeholder

            $maxDiseaseCountQuery = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                                    ->select ('MAX(disease_count) AS max_disease_count')
                                    ->from ($diseaseCountSqlQuery)
                                    ->queryAll();
            //multiple symptom query
            $diseaseCodes = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                            ->select ('ICD10')
                            ->from ($maxDiseaseCountQuery)
                            ->join ($diseaseCountSqlQuery, 'max_disease_count=disease_count')
                            ->queryAll();
```

The problem appears in the second command specifically the line:

```
->from ($diseaseCountSqlQuery)
```

I get an "**strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given** " error.

I can solve my problem by just copying the entire mysql command into a string and then using create command, but I wanted to use this more "elegant" way. Can someone help me fix it and explain a bit how subqueries work with query builder? Thank you :)

Comment: the error tells you exactly what the problem is: you're trying to use an array where a string is expected. you'd need to do a `foreach($diseaseCountSqlQuery as $part) { ...->from($part)}` or whatever.

Comment: ok, so is there a way to use the result table of the sql command in a different query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create subqueries like this. The first `queryAll` returns an array with results. You can't query this like it's a database. The `from()` part expects a parameter in the form of a string, not an array.

Try it like this:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('complete query, including subquery')->queryAll();
```

Or use PHP to filter the results after executing the first query.

More info on createCommand:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#createCommand-detail
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand

Comment: Do you have any useful resources so I can understand the use of createCommand that way better?

Comment: Take a look at the links I've added to the answer.